# Android how to implement live comments?

Tags: android, animation

I searched android live comments implementation but cannot find anywhere. Can anyone give me an hint an elegant way to handle it?

The older comments will move up when new comments are inserted, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzWWf.png)
I have a get api fetching 10 latest comments in json format.
I am thinking I can call this api every 5 seconds and insert the new comment in my comments list.

But which structure do I need use for comments moving up?

Comment: your task is too complex. What is the problem? You can't just ask somebody to do your work instead of you.

Comment: How to do a view's animation? I need the comment move up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to fetch live comments is to use **Android Service** which works in the main UI Thread/Worker Thread, even the app is destroyed.
[Best way to find service and its uses.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Do you think if it is efficient or a normal thing to call the get api every 5 seconds? Will it consume too much data?

Comment: @user6791548 It's efficient to use because every time comments are added into your App, Service works in your background to process your get API even after the app is destroyed. When a user leaves and comes back, the service will provide the data fetched during the app is not in use.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Pleasure. Add a comment for any help. I'm currently working on the same thing, might help you in future.

Comment: Thanks, are you also working on live comments, if I want to update comments, do I apply translate animation for the comment?